# MySQL - Where relation exists add a where, ignore where if not exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a flights table and a bookings table.

Flights has a column, `max_passengers`

Flights have bookings in way of the bookings table referencing a the flight_id

I am using this in laravel / PHP but I am looking help with the actual SQL because its driving me a bit loopy I can currently query a flight and work out the number of free places left by using `sum(bookings.places_booked)` then sumtracting this number from the `max_passengers` but how could I write SQL that does:

- Randomly selects flight
- If bookings are against this flight sum the amount of places booked and add a where < max_passengers

I can do this part but how can you make it so if no bookings are made against a flight the join / where becomes optional and doesn't matter because the max_passengers would be the number of free places.

I had thought about adding a `free_places` column to the flights table but it would come with issues which the current setup avoids.

```
SELECT flights.*, bookings.*
FROM flights 
LEFT JOIN bookings ON flights.id = bookings.flight_id
WHERE sum(bookings.places_booked) < flights.max_passengers
GROUP BY flights.id
ORDER BY flights.id ASC
```

This is the thing I am trying to achive but as I said I don't know how to make the join / where optional so where no relation exists it doesn't matter about checking.

EDIT (Final SQL):

```
SELECT flights.*, bookings.*
FROM flights 
LEFT JOIN bookings ON flights.id = bookings.flight_id
GROUP BY flights.id
HAVING COALESCE(sum(bookings.places_booked),0) < flights.max_passengers
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things :
 1) You should use the `HAVING` clause and not the `WHERE` clause for aggregation functions (your query should throw an error).

2) Use `COALESCE()` to replace the value from `NULL` to an actual value. This is the second reason why your query is not working. When there is no match , `bookings.places_booked` is null , then the condition is rendered as `NULL < flights.max_passenger` , which will always be false.

```
GROUP BY flights.id
HAVING COALESCE(sum(bookings.places_booked),0) < MAX(flights.max_passengers)
ORDER BY flights.id
```